# Custom Firefox / Chromium install with Pre-installed extension (non enterprise)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, chromium

i wanted to build a custom browser install that would fit the following specs, i found ways to do it using enterprise deployement, but my intent is to distribute it to friends and family without having to go through the enterprise distribution.

1. Can be sourced from Firefox or Chromium (or even other as webkit)
2. Should be easy to customize (ideally no C++ coding)
3. Should be able to embed extension or hard code the extension within the browser. (i've coded a custom adblock that is lighter and faster than the ones on FF or Chrome store and would also like to embed TOR connection extension)
4. Remove the ability to install other extensions (i want to ensure this browser cannot be victim of bloatware extensions installs)
5. Customize UI
6. Protect the browser against Search engine / HP / New tab settings change.

If you could point me to the right direction it would be awesome and i'll make sure to share this browser's link here once done.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this in the corner of my eye and figured I'd share this question/answer to possibly help you:

[Standard way to build a Chrome extension into Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium)