# Chromium - How to make an actual installer out of mini_installer.exe

Tags: windows-installer, chromium

After building chromium from source, you can create a "mini installer" for Windows by running

```
ninja -C out\BuildFolder mini_installer
```

This works fine and creates a `mini_installer.exe` in `out\BuildFolder`.

But when I launch `mini_installer.exe` it just launches chromium. It doesn't open a nice installer interface.

So instead I am using InnoSetup to install the chromium files, and I'm not even using `mini_installer.exe`.

Can someone please describe what this "mini_installer" is supposed to accomplish? Can it prevent me from having to go through the trouble of making my own InnoSetup installer for my fork of Chromium?

Comment: I can give you a detailed information about this question. I am writing it right now :)

Comment: thanks! i'll delete my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mini_installer` is just a packer which packs the following files:

```
 1. CHROME.PACKED.7z
 2. setup.exe
```

These files should be present in your `BuildFolder`. `CHROME.PACKED.7z` packs `Chrome.7z` which includes your Chromium files and folders.

`mini_installer` will extract those two files to a temporary directory and then execute `setup.exe`. For instance if `mini_installer.exe` was executed with `--system-level` argument, it will pass those arguments to `setup.exe`:

```
"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\CWB_341A7.tmp\setup.exe" --install-archive="C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\CWB_341A7.tmp\CHROME.PACKED.7Z" --system-level
```

That temporary folder name should be different for Chromium and Chrome cause we modified our fork to use `CWB` prefix

So, it's `setup.exe` which is responsible for the actual installation and uninstallation process. When you uninstall your Chromium fork `setup.exe` will be executed with the following arguments:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\YourChromium\Application\66.0.3359.139\Installer\setup.exe --uninstall --system-level
```

Note: if you pass `--system-level` then it will be installed for all the users.

The arguments you pass to `mini_installer` will be stored in registry so the same argument will be passed to `setup.exe` when you uninstall it. It should typically be stored here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\CompanyName\Update\ClientState\{Your-Chromium-fork-GUID} (for system-level installations)
```

The value of `UninstallArguments` and `UninstallString` will be read and used when uninstalling your Chromium fork.

Hope that helps

EDIT:

Just adding this info for anyone who might find this useful. There are various command line options for the installer which you can find here:

`chrome\installer\util\master_preferences_constants.cc`

Comment: Yes this helps a lot. Question - what if I want some command line arguments added to chromium when it is started up (most importantly, logging). Is there a way to either A) tell mini_installer not to start chrome just install or B) can i tell it to always give chromium some sort of arguments?
Because if it launches chromium right away I won't be able to see logging during "First Run = true"

Comment: Chromium already supports logging: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging You can add or modify existing command line arguments or switches too. Existing switches can be found here: ``src\chrome\common\chrome_switches.cc`` To add your own switch refer to the methods of base::CommandLine class: ``src\base\command_line.cc``

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant to ask was how can I get the `mini_installer.exe` to launch chrome with `--enable-logging --v=1` so that my first run has logging?

Comment: You should modify Chromium source code to do so. If you open this file: ``src\chrome\browser\first_run\first_run.cc``, there's a method ``IsChromeFirstRun`` which will return a boolean value indicating if it was first run or not. If it returns true then you can append that switch but then again you will have to modify Chromium source code.

Comment: I think I found it. `chrome\installer\setup\setup_main.cc` has a `kDoNotLaunchChrome` option

Comment: BTW, if you pass ``--system-level`` argument then I am sure it won't launch Chromium. I might be wrong though but try it

Comment: I created another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307180/chromium-mini-installer-ignores-branding 
can't seem to get this to respect my branding.

Comment: @Asesh I have a question about chromium auto-update with which you can help as I saw your post in chromium devs about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710054/how-to-link-customized-chromium-fork-with-omaha