# Chromium - mini_installer ignores branding

Tags: windows-installer, chromium, ninja

After building chromium from source, you can create a "mini installer" for Windows by running

```
ninja -C out\BuildFolder mini_installer
```

This works fine and creates a `mini_installer.exe` in `out\BuildFolder`.

see [Chromium - How to make an actual installer out of mini_installer.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305917/chromium-how-to-make-an-actual-installer-out-of-mini-installer-exe) for more details.

But after running `mini_installer.exe`, the application ignores my branding and `grd` resource customizations.

It is supposed to use "IDS_PRODUCT_NAME_BASE" which I have definitely customized.

Here are the files I applied my branding in:

- `chrome\app\chromium_strings.grd`
- `chrome\app\settings_chromium_strings.grdp`
- `chrome\app\theme\chromium\BRANDING`

But it seems to be ignoring them.

- The program is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromium` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\CustomProductName`
- The executable is still named `chrome.exe` instead of `CustomProductName.exe`

How does one customize that?

Comment: What version of Chromium are you working on right now? And in your ``BuildFolder``, do you see ``chrome.exe`` or ``CustomProductName.exe``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branding won't change the name of generated executable files. You should modify `src\chrome\BUILD.gn` to change the name from `chrome.exe` to `CustomProductName.exe` as specified below:

```
if (is_win) {
action("reorder_imports") {
script = "//build/win/reorder-imports.py"

# See comment in chrome_dll.gypi in the hardlink_to_output
# target for why this cannot be 'initial' like the DLL.
inputs = [
  "$root_out_dir/initialexe/CustomProductName.exe",
]
outputs = [
  "$root_out_dir/CustomProductName.exe",
]
if (symbol_level != 0) {
  outputs += [ "$root_out_dir/CustomProductName.exe.pdb" ]
}
... later in the file ...
chrome_binary("chrome_initial") {
  if (is_win) {
    output_name = "initialexe/CustomProductName"
```

Doing so will generate `CustomProductName.exe` instead of `Chrome.exe` in your `BuildFolder`. After that, you should notify mini installer too by modifying this file: `src\chrome\installer\mini_installer\BUILD.gn`:

```
action(archive_name) {
script = "//chrome/tools/build/win/create_installer_archive.py"

release_file = "chrome.release"

inputs = [
  "$chrome_dll_file",
  "$root_out_dir/CustomProductName.exe",
  "$root_out_dir/locales/en-US.pak",
  "$root_out_dir/setup.exe",
  "//chrome/tools/build/win/makecab.py",
  release_file,
]
```

Those changes will only change the name of executable files. You will have to modify source code to reflect those changes too.

Assign the name of your browser executable in this file: `src\chrome\installer\util\util_constants.cc`

```
const wchar_t kChromeExe[] = L"CustomProductName.exe";
```

The path to installation folder should be specified in this file: 
`src\chrome\install_static\chromium_install_modes.cc`

```
const wchar_t kCompanyPathName[] = L"CompanyName";

const wchar_t kProductPathName[] = L"CustomProductName";
```

Similarly, you will have to change company name and app name in this file too: `src\chrome\installer\util\browser_distribution.cc`. I am not sure if the current version of Chromium still uses data from `BrowserDistribution` class.

Let me know if it works. I just went through our repo history to find out those changes.

UPDATE:

The comments reveal a couple more places:

Open `chrome_elf/BUILD.gn` and change here:

```
$root_out_dir/CustomProductName.exe
```

And change here: `chrome/installer/mini_installer/chrome.release`

```
CustomProductName.exe: %(ChromeDir)s\
```

And change here: `build/win/reorder-imports.py`

```
input_image = os.path.join(input_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe')
output_image = os.path.join(output_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe')
... later on in the file ...
for fname in glob.iglob(os.path.join(input_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe.*')):
```

Comment: This change probably requires a full clean right? I got `The file: //out/CustomProductName/initialexe/CustomProductName.exe is listed as an input or source for the target: //chrome:reorder_imports but no targets in the build generate that file.` but i'm guessing that is due to a need to clean

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza You don't have to clean. ``ninja`` should automatically detect changes to ``BUILD.gn`` and then generate ``CustomProductName.exe``. Isn't that file generated when you use this command: ``ninja -C out\BuildFolder chrome``. That command should build your browser executable file w/o building mini installer

Comment: Yeah even the `gn gen out/CustomProductName "--args=is_debug=false"` throws that error now. there must be a .gn file missing a change somewhere. haven't had much time to track it down but i'll dig in when i can and see if i can find it

Comment: You don't have to tell ``gn`` to ``gen`` again. You should have run the usual build command instead: ``ninja -C out\BuildFolder mini_installer, it will automatically detect changes and start compiling again.

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant to mention - i tried that. All ninja commands stop working after making the changes here with the error `The file: //out/CustomProductName/initialexe/CustomProductName.exe is listed as an input or source for the target: //chrome:reorder_imports but no targets in the build generate that file.`

Comment: Looks like you will have to modify ``chrome_elf/BUILD.gn`` and change here: ``"$root_out_dir/CustomProductName.exe",`` and here too: ``chrome/installer/mini_installer/chrome.release``: ``CustomProductName.exe: %(ChromeDir)s\``

Comment: Here are the spots that still have a chrome.exe in them https://pastebin.com/1R6eUah1
`still getting error: ERROR Input to target not generated by a dependency. The file: /out/CustomProductName/initialexe/CustomProductName.exe is listed as an input or source for the target: //chrome:reorder_imports but no targets in the build generate that file.`

Comment: You don't have to replace all of them. ``new_chrome.exe`` is used for browser rename dancing process when browser is updated and is in-use. Omaha client will do so. I just went through that file from our repo:   ``input_image = os.path.join(input_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe')
  output_image = os.path.join(output_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe')`` and another change in that same file: ``for fname in glob.iglob(os.path.join(input_dir, 'CustomProductName.exe.*')):``

Comment: looks like ``chrome:reorder_imports`` error message that you posted above is because ``chrome.exe`` doesn't exist or is not generated by your build system.

Comment: At this point i'm trying to run a clean build. This error is happening at configuration time

Comment: I think i found it. `chrome_binary("chrome_initial") {     if (is_win) {      output_name = "initialexe/CustomProductName"` in `chrome/BUILD.gn`