# How to change Chromium browser logo and name?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, chromium

I've built the Chromium browser on my Windows from its [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src) ([Github](https://github.com/chromium/chromium)) by following [this documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md). After doing this successfully, I've a chrome.exe file which is able to launch the browser (see screenshot).

[image: My Chromium interface]

The next thing I want to implement is to change the logo and name of Chromium (say, MyBrowser) everywhere on the browser. I'm stuck at this step. Is there any way to achieve this by modifying the code or replacing the icon?

Comment: I've made the changes and, now, I'm building the project again. If it works, I'll let you know. Btw, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to make lots of changes. Before replacing these files, please make sure the files that you are replacing with matches the resolution and format too.

If you want to change the logo of Chromium then replace these files with yours

```
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_22_mono.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_24.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_48.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_64.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_128.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/product_logo_256.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_100_percent/chromium/product_logo_16.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_100_percent/chromium/product_logo_32.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_100_percent/chromium/product_logo_name_22.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_200_percent/chromium/product_logo_16.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_200_percent/chromium/product_logo_32.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_200_percent/chromium/product_logo_name_22.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_200_percent/chromium/product_logo_name_48.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/win/tiles/Logo.png
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/win/tiles/SmallLogo.png
```

Then replace this icon file:
For Windows:

```
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/win/chromium.ico
```

For macOS:

```
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/mac/app.icns
```

To change the name of the browser and messages displayed in Chromium, open and modify these files

```
src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/BRANDING
src/chrome/app/generated_resources.grd
src/chrome/app/chromium_strings.grd
```

You should replace `Chromium` or `Chrome` references from the above files with your brand

Comment: What about these? Do any of these need to change?

- chrome\build.gn
- chrome\installer\mini_installer\build.gn
- chrome\installer\util\util_constants.cc
- build\config\chrome_build.gni

- chrome\install_static\chromium_install_modes.cc

- chrome\installer\mini_installer\chrome.release

Comment: @MickeyKawick This question is just for changing logo, icons and displayed name. If you want to change the executable file names etc then you might want to look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307180/chromium-mini-installer-ignores-branding/50308199#50308199

Comment: @Asesh I'm not able to make changes in these two places: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215821/change-chromium-icon-and-chrome-text-to-custom-icon-and-text-in-the-address-ba

Comment: @Asesh It did not work for android. how can I change name of app in android?

Comment: @hamid You should have looked at the tags, this is for Windows only. Sorry I don't do Android development so I have no idea.

Comment: @Asesh by changing name , was unable to change in window task manager. it still is showing Chromium(32 bit) not a changed name. it there any specific place that we need to change on ?

Comment: @Anjulkhanal did you change the references here too: `chrome/common/chrome_constants.cc`?  Look at my above comment, there's another thread for changing Chromium filename and references.

Comment: @Asesh  i changed that as well. rebuilt and tested. unfortunately that doesnot work for me. i still see chromium in my taskmanager process