# Change Chromium icon and "chrome" text to custom icon and text in the Address Bar

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium

I'm building the Chromium browser on my Windows pc. I'm following this codebase: https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-windows

I only need help in removing two things in the Address Bar (see the image): the "chrome" text and the grey Chromium icon.

Let me know if any other information is required.

[image: chromium]

Comment: You have to find the location of the protocol chrome:// in the source code and replace it by your own protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The icon should be changed in "components/omnibox/browser/vector_icons", production.icon file.
Also, there is one additional place - "chrome/app/vector_icons/chromium", production.icon too. This icon is using with the message - "Chromium isn't your default browser".

Answer (score 2):

you should customize it in function `std::u16string LocationIconView::GetText()` (file \src\chrome\browser\ui\views\location_bar\location_icon_view.cc)