# rebrand GUI icons of Chromium

Tags: chromium

I am building my browser from Chromium on Windows. I carried out steps from this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

It builds successfully and browser runs well. I also rebranded all pics in `src\chrome\app\theme\chromium`, but the logo icons in GUI are still chromium ones

[image]

Where can I change these in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change those logo you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166411/how-to-change-chromium-browser-logo-and-name/64167597#64167597)

Now to change the vectorized icon which is displayed in the tab bar, you should modify this file

```
components/omnibox/browser/vector_icons/product.icon
```

You can find more info about vectorized icons [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/components/vector_icons/README.md)

This is how the code of vectorized icon looks like [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/omnibox/browser/vector_icons/product.icon;l=1?q=product.icon&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:components%2F)

Hope that helps!

Comment: great, thank you Asesh.

Answer (score 0):

change the chromium icon:

In settings page

```
ui/webui/resources/images/chrome_logo_dark.svg
```

In new page favicon

```
src/chrome/app/theme/default_100_percent/favicon_ntp.png
src/chrome/app/theme/default_200_percent/favicon_ntp.png
```

In address bar

```
chromium/src/components/omnibox/broswer/vector_icons/product.icon
```