# Custom chrome browser / installer?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I know that this question was asked multiple times before, but every answer I found was 1. Not existing anymore or 2. Not a real answer.

I just want to create a custom chrome 'version'. This version should have a custom icon, should run as 2. Chrome (like another app) and should have a custom name + design + a preinstalled extension. How can I do this? I have seen it before.

I do *not* want to clone 200gb of chromium!!!

Is there a solution offered from Google, or can I build a custom installer somehow?

Pls help. Kind regards.

Comment: If you don't want to load Google in some window on a desktop application and don't want to use Chromium either I doubt it's possible. If you require a "version" of _Chrome_ you can preinstall extensions on Chromium http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions  and modify the UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166411/how-to-change-chromium-browser-logo-and-name

Comment: Yeah, I could just change the logo files and the extension-save-file the ui colorchanges could also work like that. Do you know how I can install chrome into another folder? As a 2. instance?

Comment: For that you will have to modify Chromium source code and study it's source code. Chromium is a very big and rapidly changing project, so you won't find a universal answer to your question.