# changing src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/win/chromium.ico will not change application icon

Tags: windows-10, chromium

I have edited chromium.ico and built using autoninja mini_installer and it has succeeded along with building for chrome however the icon still has not changed, I have also published the build and ran on another computer and it still has the chromium icon instead of mine. I have updated, rebooted ect.

Comment: This might be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166411/how-to-change-chromium-browser-logo-and-name/64167597#64167597