# Chromium build not running after rebranding

Tags: chromium

I wanted to try to build and modify [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) in order to try and learn a few things. When I first built it and ran it (without any changes), it worked perfectly fine, however I tried changes some of the branding in order to tinker with it and it gave me an error message. I referred to two places when rebranding to see where I could change the branding:

[First link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64167597/13735351)

[Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308199/13735351)

When I ran the modified version, it gave me an error message when running:

```
[0808/205916.858263:FATAL:bundle_locations.mm(62)] Check failed: new_bundle. Failed to load the bundle at /path/to/src/out/buildTwo/RebrandName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions/94.0.4601.0
0   libbase.dylib                       0x000000010a123638 base::debug::CollectStackTrace(void**, unsigned long) + 12
1   libbase.dylib                       0x000000010a00e774 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 24
2   libbase.dylib                       0x000000010a032c1c logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 184
3   libbase.dylib                       0x000000010a033914 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 12
4   libbase.dylib                       0x0000000109ffa0f0 logging::CheckError::~CheckError() + 36
5   libbase.dylib                       0x000000010a139d5c base::mac::AssignOverridePath(base::FilePath const&, NSBundle**) + 176
6   libchrome_dll.dylib                 0x0000000104ceb5d0 SetUpBundleOverrides() + 40
7   libchrome_dll.dylib                 0x0000000104ce8f44 ChromeMain + 156
8   RebrandName                         0x00000001049b7cc0 main + 284
9   libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018efcd450 start + 4

zsh: trace trap  out/buildTwo/RebrandName.app/Contents/MacOS/RebrandName
```

I tried to investigate to see what might have happened and saw that `/path/to/src/out/buildTwo/RebrandName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Framework.framework` but in it's place is `/path/to/src/out/buildTwo/RebrandName.app/Contents/Frameworks/RebrandName Framework.framework`

I ran `out/buildTwo/RebrandName.app/Contents/MacOS/RebrandName` and this error popped up.

This is currently running on an M1 Macbook Pro on MacOS Big Sur.

I have tried searching for the fix with no luck. Please understand that I have little to no idea of what I'm doing, so if more clarification is required, please let me know and I will try to edit my question as best as I can.

Comment: I have not tried those answers on my Mac as I do Chromium development on Windows only but you can try modifying the references from these source files and try again: https://source.chromium.org/search?q=%22Chromium%20Framework.framework%22&ss=chromium

Comment: @Asesh I tried editing the ones that were provided from the link above, however I am getting a similar error. Instead of  `[0808/205916.858263:FATAL:bundle_locations.mm(62)]...`, I'm getting `[0810/103402.336405:FATAL:bundle_locations.mm(62)]...`, and the rest is the same. Though I didn't know you could search the source like this, so I thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

The file:
chrome/common/chrome_constants.cc

Change PRODUCT_STRING constant