# Chromium consuming above 50% CPU and crashes while playing a video

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-debugging

I have built the latest stable version of Chromium (at the time of writing 100.0.4896.88) in debug as well as in release mode.
I changed the name and logo of the browser by making changes in some files, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166411/how-to-change-chromium-browser-logo-and-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307180/chromium-mini-installer-ignores-branding/50308199#50308199) post.

Currently, I am facing issues with CPU usage. Every time I open chromium or a new tab in Chromium, CPU usage jumps above 25% and then comes back to 1 or 2%. After opening around 10 tabs, it reaches around 70-80%. I tested chromium before making any changes in files and the same thing was happening with CPU consumption.

The second issue is about playing videos. When I try to play any video like YouTube in debug mode, the browser immediately crashes. In release mode, it plays it for a few seconds before crashing.

After building the chromium, I use the following command to create a mini_installer.exe

```
autoninja -C out/Release mini_installer.exe
```

So maybe I am doing something wrong which generating the installer because for the rest of it I am following the actual documentation? Any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: As you are building from source, why not debug and find out why it's happening? You have to attach your debugger to renderer process to find out why it's happening or analyze crash dump

Comment: That's a good thought. I just wanted to confirm is it normal behaviour of Chromium or is it only happening with me? Because I have downloaded Chromium .exe from Google, although it doesn't crashes on playing video, it also eats a lot of CPU like 40-45% on opening new tabs.