# How to distribute Chromium binary after compiling? Directory has over 39GB

Tags: windows, compilation, chromium, gn

I want to distribute Chromium I just compiled. The problem is, just after compiling, the directory with the binary weights over 39GB!
How can I filter only needed for operation files? I think it should be at most about 1GB.
I am on Windows, and followed instructions from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

[image]
The directory in question looks like this: several subdirectories, and ~1400 single files in root.

Ideally I'm looking for specific guidline, including files and folders I must keep.

Comment: The executable and satellite DLLs are probably minimally required. I imagine many of the space is “.o” object files and test executables, or..? Although it seems like the should be a make dist or some such ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to distribute mini installer only which will be in your build folder as `mini_installer.exe`. You can build mini installer by executing the following command:

```
ninja -C out\YourBuildFolder mini_installer
```

Basically mini installer is just a packer which packs the following files:

```
setup.exe
chrome.packed.7z
```

More information on it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305917/chromium-how-to-make-an-actual-installer-out-of-mini-installer-exe/50306193#50306193). So executing mini installer will extract those files and execute `setup.exe`, which will then install your Chromium fork. Also, for distributing your fork, you should build release versions which you can specify when you run this command:

```
gn args out\YourBuildFolder
```

Basically it will open `args.gn` file located in `out\YourBuildFolder` and then you set:

```
is_debug = false
```

You might need those files and folders for debugging your Chromium fork as it includes the debug symbols, which are required for debugging.