# How to link customized chromium fork with omaha?

Tags: windows, chromium, auto-update

I have been working on a chromium fork to build a custom desktop browser, however I am stuck at implementing the auto-update mechanism for browser.

I am using Crystalnix omaha server and have successfully set it up on docker but couldn't find any guide or tutorials on what changes should need to be made on browser side and where?
If somebody could give some pointers or provide a link to some documentation would be great.

Comment: This is going to be a big and complex task. You will have to modify your browser to talk to Google Omaha client:  https://github.com/google/omaha then Google Omaha client will talk to your Omaha server. Omaha client is responsible for checking for updates and initiating the installation process. That's for Windows only

Comment: @Asesh is there any open-source browser that has already implemented this or any link to the tutorial that could help?

Comment: I don't think there's one. We had to study the source code and do lots of debugging to to make it work. In the mean time you should try to find the flow which will call this method: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/webui/help/version_updater_win.cc;l=28  and search for that method to find out where it's being called from: https://source.chromium.org/search?q=CheckForUpdate&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc Also automatic update integration is disabled via `BUILDFLAG(GOOGLE_CHROME_BRANDING)` directives