# how to sign mini installer of brave and chromium

Tags: build, chromium, brave

I have a EV code signing certificate PFX file and password.
How do I apply it while brave or chromium mini installer.

brave command to build mini_installer is:
npm run create_dist

and chromium forks are build using this:
autoninja -C out\Default mini_installer

but they dont create signed installers.

how to generate installer in which all files like chrome.dll and chrome.exe are signed to code signing certificate.

Edit:
I tried signing all exe and dll files inside build directory and ran mini_installer command, but them chromium started building all of those 20k files and after that all those files became unsigned again and mini_installer had those unsigned ones

Comment: You will have to manually sign `mini_installer`. But if you want to sign files inside `mini_installer` for e.g., chrome.exe chrome.dll etc then you will have to modify the build script and digitally sign files before mini installer is built

Comment: Thankyou @Asesh but I think chromium/brave must have a way of signing it since they sign all of the executable files inside installer

Comment: I tried signing all exe and dll files inside build directory and ran mini_installer command, but them chromium started building all of those 20k files and after that all those files became unsigned again and mini_installer had those unsigned ones

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way to do so. Chromium uses build tools to build `chrome.7z` which packs those binary files and I think `mini_installer` too. You will have to sign those files before they are packed as `chrome.7z` which is packed into `mini_installer` [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305917/chromium-how-to-make-an-actual-installer-out-of-mini-installer-exe/50306193#50306193).

You will have to modify this script: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/tools/build/win/create_installer_archive.py;l=1?q=create_installer_archive&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc to digitally sign binary files before the installer is built. Go through the script.

You will have to execute [Microsoft's signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) to use your certificate and password from there to code sign binary files like `chrome.exe`, `chrome.dll` etc before they are packed into `chrome.7z` archive.

All the relevant changes to make it work as you are intending, is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: I have edited the question, what if we can sign all exe inside build folder without triggering rebuild of those files?

Comment: @NaeemMalik Answer to your another question: that's expected because Chromium's build system detected changes of the compiled files. That's why I told you to modify that script and sign those binary files from there.

Comment: I would much rather prefer making a script that loops each dll or exe filie and stores its modified date in a variable then applies signing and then changes modified date of the file

Comment: modifying chromium files is a mess, even after you change then whenever you rebase/update browser version code , you will have to rewrite all of your code again, so not modifying chromium is the way Brave prefers it and I do too

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution in python.

make build, then run this script and then make mini_installer build then run this script again and then build your installer and it including everything inside will be signed.

you need to replace:

`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x64\\signtool.exe`

`D:\\Asil\\src\\out\\Component` with your build folder

`C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\asil-certificate\\new-Halalz (2).pfx`

`PFX_Password`

```
import os
import datetime
import subprocess

def apply_certificate(file_path, pfx_file, password):
    # Command to sign the file with the certificate
    signtool= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x64\\signtool.exe"
    sign_command = f'"{signtool}" sign /f "{pfx_file}" /p "{password}" "{file_path}"'
    print(sign_command)
    # Execute the command
    subprocess.run(sign_command, shell=True)

def main(directory_path, pfx_file, password):
    # Validate if the provided path is a directory
    if not os.path.isdir(directory_path):
        print(f"The specified path '{directory_path}' is not a directory.")
        return

    # Loop through each file in the directory
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)

        # Check if the file is a DLL or EXE
        if filename.lower().endswith(('.dll', '.exe')):
            # Get the current modified date and time
            current_modified_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))

            print(f"File: {filename}")
            print(f"Current Modified Time: {current_modified_time}")

            # Apply EV code signing certificate
            apply_certificate(file_path, pfx_file, password)

            # Set the modified date and time back to what it was before
            os.utime(file_path, (current_modified_time.timestamp(), current_modified_time.timestamp()))

            print("EV Code Signing Certificate Applied.")
            print(f"Modified Time Set to: {current_modified_time}")
            print("")

if _name_ == "_main_":
    # Specify the directory path

    directory_path = "D:\\Asil\\src\\out\\Component"

    # Specify the path to the PFX file and its password
    pfx_file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\asil-certificate\\new-Halalz (2).pfx"
    password = "PFX_Password"

    # Call the main function
    main(directory_path, pfx_file, password)
```