# ERROR at //chrome/browser/extensions/default_extensions/BUILD.gn:9:1: Invalid token

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I followed this post [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium)  but it throws an error message: `//chrome/browser/extensions/default_extensions/BUILD.gn:9:1: Invalid token.`

screen console http://prntscr.com/k16ou8

all BUILD.gn

```html
# Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

if (is_win) {
  copy("default_extensions") {
    sources = [
      "external_extensions.json",
   "SuperSMM.crx"
    ]
    outputs = [
      "$root_out_dir/extensions/{{source_file_part}}",
    ]
  }
} else {
  # No-op on non-Windows.
  group("default_extensions") {
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the contents of ``BUILD.gn``

Comment: all changes


if (is_win) {
copy("default_extensions") {
sources = [
  "external_extensions.json",
  "SuperSMM.crx"
]
outputs = [
  "$root_out_dir/extensions/{{source_file_part}}",
]

Comment: Better post the whole content of that file

Comment: that's the whole code. Output all code

Comment: It's probably because of code alignment of ``SuperSMM.crx`` in that file. Make sure ``SuperSMM.crx`` is aligned properly with ``external_extensions.json`` ie they should have the same column number