# How to build a component extension in chromium browser for windows?

Tags: chromium

I would like to build my own Chromium from source so that my extension is pre-bundled into the built distributed package of chromium browser.

How do install CRX file automatically while building chromium browser ?

I followed this article to get the code and building process.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard way to build a Chrome extension into Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium)

Comment: yes  .. I followed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium   this .. but it's getting error while building ...   "error: no member named 'ResetAndReturn' in namespace 'base' "  -- getting this error

Comment: Hi @Asesh i am waiting for ur response ... My chromium version is 88 ...