# How to build a chromium browser with pre-installed Extensions, but not coming from the Chrome store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, electron, chromium

I am building a windows/macos desktop application (with electron) who will be able to launch several custom chromium-based browser. I want the browser to have a pre-installed extension but i don't know how to do it.

I wanted to follow this : [Standard way to build a Chrome extension into Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium)
but i was stuck in the building process because it seems that the solution don't work anymmore with recent versions of chromium.

I read the chromium documentation (https://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions) but the solutions seems to only work wih extensions from the store but my extensions isn't public.

So has anyone succeeded to do this, or just know what should i do to buld this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by it was stuck in the building process? What error message do you encounter when doing so? Also Chromium is a very big and rapidly changing project. If you modify the source code, it could break any time in the following or future versions

Comment: When I use the build command (autoninja -C out\Default chrome), I am getting  the error : no member named 'ResetAndReturn' in namespace 'base'.
So If it is a bad idea to modify the source code, is there any other way to build the browser with pre-installed extension?

Comment: Chrome won't allow you install extensions outside of the Chrome web store without modifying the source code. You can load it by enabling developer mode. If I have time I will try to update that answer in the future which I answered a few years back, but don't keep any hope. So better to load your extension by enabling developer mode for now

Comment: Ok i see, thanks for the reply i will try through source code or i will use developer mode. I didn't notice that it was you who wrote the previous answer, anyway thank you for helping us