# Chromium extension Preinstall

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, webviewchromium

I want to pre-install the extension on a Chromium browser, but I don't know how to pre-install it because the official documentation is old or the information on the new one is old. Can somebody tell me?

I thought Chrome \ Browser \ resource \ default_app\external_extensions.json was that directory, but it didn't work.

[external_extensions.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIqjI.png)

Comment: Google could have answered your question. Anyways, you should checkout this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium/50305105#50305105

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard way to build a Chrome extension into Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125821/standard-way-to-build-a-chrome-extension-into-chromium)